# SP.CamlQuery().set_viewXml() returns undefined

Tags: caml-query, caml

I am trying to run a CAML query to sort through some data. Once the page finishes loading i do not get the results i want. I checked the functions and it turns out that for some reason, my CAML query returns `undefined`. It only does this after it is passed in the `set_viewXml()` function. Code provided below:

```
var runQuery = function (dateObj, query, success, failure, context) {

   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

   alert(query); // shows the CAML query
   alert(camlQuery.set_viewXml(query(dateObj))); // shows me undefined

   camlQuery.set_viewXml(query(dateObj));

   items = list.getItems(camlQuery);

   context.load(items);

   context.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);
};
```

Here is the CAML:

```
"<View>" + 
   "<Query>" +
      "<Where>" + 
         "<And>" +
            "<Eq>" +
               "<FieldRef Name='EventStartDate' />" +
               "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" +
                  dateObj.toISOString() +
               "</Value>" +
            "</Eq>" +
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"QueryID\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">2216</Value></Eq>" +
         "</And>" +
      "</Where>" +
      "<GroupBy><FieldRef Name='EventName'></FieldRef></GroupBy>"+
      "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventStartDate' /><FieldRef Name='EventEndDate' /><FieldRef Name='EventName' /></OrderBy>" +
   "</Query>" +
"</View>";
```

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the CAML query because i do not work with it on a day to day basis.

I have this code running fine in another app and when I `alert(alert(camlQuery.set_viewXml(query(dateObj)));)` I am able to see the full CAML query build (it does not return `undefined`). Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Where you define this variable in your code dateObj?

Comment: It is just some other functions above where I call the runQuery function. I am able to see the date if i alert it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue at this function `query(dateObj)` within `alert(camlQuery.set_viewXml(query(dateObj)));`

This function may be undefined or defined as `var query = function (dateObj) {}`. in this case, it will be undefined if you tried to call it like this `query (dateObj)` so try to define it as `function query(dateObj) {}`

Also, make sure that it's not defined at the same scope of `query` variable because it has the same name.

Comment: M.Qassas, I have tried your suggestion but when i change the function to `function query(dateObj)` I receive an error saying that the `query` function is not a function or is not defined. When i change it back i do not receive and error

Comment: should you share your final code , or  if you can to change its name and try again , then tell me result

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your 'query' parameter is a variable and not a function, so `query(dateObj)` will not work.

create a function outside of `var runQuery = function`:

```
    var query = function(dateObj){
      if(dateObj){
        return "<View>" + 
       "<Query>" +
          "<Where>" + 
             "<And>" +
                "<Eq>" +
                   "<FieldRef Name='EventStartDate' />" +
                   "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" +
                      dateObj.toISOString() +
                   "</Value>" +
                "</Eq>" +
                "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"QueryID\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">2216</Value></Eq>" +
             "</And>" +
          "</Where>" +
          "<GroupBy><FieldRef Name='EventName'></FieldRef></GroupBy>"+
          "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventStartDate' /><FieldRef Name='EventEndDate' /><FieldRef Name='EventName' /></OrderBy>" +
       "</Query>" +
    "</View>";
  }
  else {
    // return something else
  }
}
```

then when you, remove `query` as a parameter to your `runQuery` function, and then call `query(dateObj);` from inside runQuery.  It's important that your query function return a string that's CAML in order to set it as the viewXML properly.

You can create a more comprehensive query function to handle the proper CAML query to make it more dynamic, but for your original question, the function above should work.